# How can I wait for the result before it is processed?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to Node and trying to understand callbacks and promises. I am using an open-source HTTP benchmark module to pull data from a specific URL and process the result after it gets the data. Here is my code

```
'use strict'

const autocannon = require('autocannon')

const instance = autocannon({
        url: 'http://localhost:3000',
        connections: 5,
        duration: 5
}, (err, result) => handleResults(result))

async function handleResults (res){
    try{
        let abReport = [];
        abReport.push(
          'Test Completed:' + '\n' +
          'Time taken for tests:' + res.duration + '\n' +
          'Total Concurrent Connections:' + res.connections + '\n' +
          'URL:' + res.url + '\n' +
          'Total Errors:' + res.errors + '\n' +
          'Total Timeouts:' + res.timeouts + '\n'
        )
        console.log(abReport.join('\n'));
    }
    catch(error) {
            console.error(error);
    }
}
```

`autocanon` is passing the output to handleResults but handleResults errors out with an error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'duration' of undefined`. I am trying to find a way for handleResults to process only after the value is successfully passed from autocannon.

Comment: Why did you declare `handleResults` as an `async` function? It's actually a callback function and no `Promise` return. And can you show the `console.log(res)` in `handleResults` function?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using async await, you can update the code,

```
'use strict'

const autocannon = require('autocannon');

async function handleResults (res){
    try{
        let abReport = [];
        abReport.push(
          'Test Completed:' + '\n' +
          'Time taken for tests:' + res.duration + '\n' +
          'Total Concurrent Connections:' + res.connections + '\n' +
          'URL:' + res.url + '\n' +
          'Total Errors:' + res.errors + '\n' +
          'Total Timeouts:' + res.timeouts + '\n'
        )
        console.log(abReport.join('\n'));
    }
    catch(error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}

const getAbReport  = async () => {
    try {
            const result = await autocannon({
            url: 'http://localhost:3000',
            connections: 5,
            duration: 5,
        });
        await handleResults(result);
    } catch(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}

getAbReport();
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be waiting for results to be posted.
https://pastebin.com/QmK9U0wu

Answer (score 0):

Change `(err, result) => handleResults(result)` to

```
(err, result) => {
   if (err != null) return; // or do some error handling
   handleResults(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work using the following code:

```
'use strict'

const autocannon = require('autocannon');

const getAbReport  = async () => {
    try {
        const instance = await autocannon({
            url: 'http://localhost:3000',
            connections: 5,
            duration: 5
        }, (err, result) => handleResults(result));
    } catch(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}

async function handleResults(result) {
    try{
        let abReport = [];
        abReport.push(
          'Test Completed:' + '\n' +
          'Time taken for tests:' + result.duration + '\n' +
          'Total Concurrent Connections:' + result.connections + '\n' +
          'URL:' + result.url + '\n' +
          'Total Errors:' + result.errors + '\n' +
          'Total Timeouts:' + result.timeouts + '\n'
        )
        console.log(abReport.join('\n'));
    }
    catch(error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}

getAbReport();
```

Comment: How do I do this in cli?